# mysql - select MAX value by a group return wrong values of other column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to find **MAX** value by the `code` and my data like below:

| id | date | code | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 74 | 2022-01-04 | B | 64 |
| 91 | 2022-01-07 | A | 174 |
| 112 | 2022-01-11 | B | 128 |
| 245 | 2022-01-12 | C | 841 |
| 550 | 2022-01-14 | A | 79 |
| 780 | 2022-01-20 | B | 55 |
| 821 | 2022-01-23 | D | 45 |
| 868 | 2022-01-28 | C | 50 |
| 890 | 2022-02-02 | B | 467 |
| 891 | 2022-02-03 | D | 58 |
| 892 | 2022-02-04 | A | 472 |

What I expect, it will return like below:

| id | date | code | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 245 | 2022-01-12 | C | 841 |
| 890 | 2022-02-02 | B | 467 |
| 891 | 2022-02-03 | D | 58 |
| 892 | 2022-02-04 | A | 472 |

I'm using below query:

```
select x.id, x.date, x.code, y.yprice
from data AS x
inner join
(
select id, date, code, MAX(price) AS yprice
from data
group by code
) y
on x.id = y.id AND x.code = y.code
```

and give me below result:

[image]

About the result:
The value of **MAX** is right, however the **id** and **date** is wrong.

Any idea to fix the query?

Thank You...

Comment: I'd try `GROUP BY id, date, code`, and perhaps include the date in the join conditions.

Comment: @jarlh I have tried it, but it didnt work. it will not show Max value but show all record.

Comment: Either the column is a part of GROUP BY expression or it is an argument of aggregate function or it returns indefinite value. So "the id and date is wrong" is correct, you see 3rd-variant issue. Read about incomplete grouping and `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode.

Comment: @Akina in my case, is it enabled or not?

Comment: `SELECT @@sql_mode;` will give you an answer. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html And study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html "MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY to permit selecting fields that are not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause. If you are not getting the results that you expect from your query, please read the description of GROUP BY found in Section 12.20, “Aggregate Functions”." and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @Akina Is it safe to run `@@sql_mode` in shared hosting? i see some warning for running this command...

Comment: This is safe - you read, not alter. Warning may be not related - execute `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after and look at the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT X.ID,X.DATE,X.CODE,X.PRICE
FROM
(
 SELECT C.id,C.date,C.code,C.price,
  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.code ORDER BY C.Price DESC)XCOL
    FROM test AS C
)X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

Could you please try this one

Comment: Hi, it does not work

Comment: now, it work, because it missing `FROM [table]` at line 5... Thank You